# How to reset forgotten Yahoo! password?

Tags: yahoo, yahoo-mail

I forgot my Yahoo! password. I tried many times to recover it but I can’t. I called Yahoo! customer service who they said that I have to pay for it.

Please help me to recover it.

Answer (score 0):

You question is a bit unclear. You have not mentioned what error you are facing when you tried to recover it.

From Yahoo! help: [Reset your forgotten password](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/mail-for-desktop/SLN2047.html?impressions=true)

> Use our [Yahoo Password Helper](https://login.yahoo.com/account/challenge/username?authMechanism=secondary&yid=&done=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.yahoo.com&s=eyJ2IjoyLCJjIjp0cnVlfQ--~V7oZ20C2LiUDFw7OXJFbeq985IsJAeJyYFn3BemYJjfZEBCTeRQi.HAbhhdBp.iyzOQojrYM0PvpIe_aOoHR3IU90b0TgxvQsARAp_.YPkcVxIIvkJ14U_06lw6ulY_mV4pmFHKyKZsC3fVsRry2ou_Pp7AS_iCQj3tfDi87Yfxw2vexmDPpX3CW8qBPZjA2f.d4kJJrd6T1tHy9SfPOsma61tEMWKQ1AbaYcjwl9gnSgH06ugjJdD.2uzcJKs8fX9F8oap5T8kGbK5tsDqTzTxfsh3OsSUDEcq_h3zY.k1xTCX7CN3m0dBV4g6m3Bs1PjoqWIaCS3JBXZGr4Uju2QS5DDXQoeNeWgNSw_aY70mwqzlbZ6pDvzIltwGooXZpz4l9_0IFkg8z0jaaqI_3zKbF4O5cotMCC6YD1jilgUj09fWdt5ithHneM3SKoFJgKvYsBvKU62UWR9KBtA.yjQNHRUOtrlrZ0dX3SnonpvzzhaoElvDeJfPCLzE-&c=eyJ2IjoyLCJjIjp0cnVlfQ--~mE3E1jq2LgXpT6hZuG2lx3ARAg1gje0RBa4td4kQZPyPSo2WAPStYbNcGRj2TP9xmX9d2OzGP8j5T02HTZm_XkmLsz25RUh2lBA74xRoc38TvtaWE0J_b1jOBaGyQDYBg5u_L7XDd5INn3ZqalV.JMuKxBPKRzgwJqsQ0S4bE7dVLw1bRjeywDE1X8ZY25_g.MaYATvkkgjc__JHvuoKn8bmLjHxDGEpUHLw3NIU9Mhtn0KM1g--&crumb=xhwxvO5VQhh) to reset your password and regain access.
>
> If you need a little more help, select one of the methods below for exact steps to securely verify your identity and reset your password.

There are three methods:

> 1. Mobile phone
> 2. Alternate email address
> 3. Secret questions

You can use any of the one option and reset your password.